# How to dynamically populate bootstrap grids using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to display match stats boxes using bootstrap grids. Total 16 grids 4X4 i.e each row contains 4 columns. Instead of creating 16 match stats boxes is there any way to dynamically populate the data using ReactJS.

In app.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import Content from './components/content';
import Pagination from './components/pagination';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar/>
        <Content/>
        <Pagination/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In Content.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './content.css';

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches:[],
            loading:true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        matches:res,
        loading:false
      })
    })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>>Loading...</div>
        }

    return (
      <div>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div id="one">
                    <p class="match">Match {this.state.matches[0].id}</p>
                    <p><h4>{this.state.matches[0].team1}</h4></p>
                    <p>VS</p>
                    <p><h4>{this.state.matches[0].team2}</h4></p>
                    <div class="winner">
                        <p><h3>Winner</h3></p>
                        <p><h4>{this.state.matches[0].winner}</h4></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stats">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Stats</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

In content.js there is only 1 match stats box and instead of hard coding 16 boxes how can I prevent code redundant code in render function.

Current view of my web app:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your code into separate `Table`, `Row`, and `Cell` components. That way you can add your data to `Table` and it can feed the appropriate data to the rows, and the rows can feed appropriate data to the cells.

Here's a rough example to get you started:

```js
function Table({data}) {
  return (
    <table>
      {data.map(row => <Row data={row} />)}
    </table>
  )
}

function Row({data}) {
  return (
    <tr>
      {data.map(cell => <Cell data={cell} />)}
    </tr>
  )
}

function Cell({data}) {
  return (
    <td>{data}</td>
  )
}

const data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12]
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #454545;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks got it. So in this way can I populate my bootstrap grids because total number of columns for bootstrap grids is 12 ?

Comment: Sure, I guess you can do what you want. I think the best thing first is to make sure the format of the data is suitable for the project. So if it's just a single array of elements maybe think of changing it so it's a an array of arrays _n_ columns in length like I have in the example. That makes it easier to build the components.

Comment: The data which I want to populate is arrays see screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/puaAj is your method suitable for my JSON data.

Comment: That's an array of objects. So I'm assuming that you want each object's information as one row in the table? If you add that data to a jsfiddle I can take a look.

Comment: you are using `.map` method but if I have 100 objects then it will iterate over all objects but I want it to iterate till 16 objects only. Also I want to display match info in vertical column form and not tabular (as in your jsfiddle code) you can see screenshot in my question I want to display matches in that form.

Comment: Then just `arr.slice(0, 16)` the part of the array you want to display and pass that in as the data. As for the rest, I expect you can work it out given the information in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the map function. Please check the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './content.css';

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches: [],
            loading: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('api/matches')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                this.setState({
                    matches: res,
                    loading: false
                })
            })
    }

    renderMatches() {
        return this.state.matches.map(match => {
            return (
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div id="one">
                        <p class="match">Match {match.id}</p>
                        <p><h4>{match.team1}</h4></p>
                        <p>VS</p>
                        <p><h4>{match.team2}</h4></p>
                        <div class="winner">
                            <p><h3>Winner</h3></p>
                            <p><h4>{match.winner}</h4></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stats">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Stats</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>>Loading...</div>
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    {this.renderMatches()}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: I want to display 16 boxes i.e 4X4 so do I need to write `{this.renderMatches()}` 16 times. As you can see in my code column size is 3 which should add upto 12 i.e 4 boxes.

Comment: {this.renderMatches()} will create 16 div with class col-lg-3 as we are using the map function for the looping.

Comment: Total 577 JSON objects are returned(`matches[0],matches[1]....matches[576]`) so when will `map` stop lopping.

Comment: The second parameter passed to map function is index. So we can have a logic where we check the page no. and current index to show the 16 matches for the current page.

Comment: I did not get what you said. Which second parameter to map function ? Also I could not understand this line -> `So we can have a logic where we check the page no. and current index to show the 16 matches for the current page`